# standard feedback button in many sites?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I noticed that many website have a nice 'feedback' button in their page.
It usually appear on the left side and it is displayed vertically 'f e e d b a c k' .

see http://www.protectedplanet.net/ for an example.

I would like to know (Because I could not figure that out) if this is achieved just by a css transformation , javascript
(and if so how to do it) or if it just a gif/jpg ?

Thanks

p.s.
Rather than guessing can people explain how exactly it works. 
For example if people says it's an image where is it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usually is a background image (for compatibility with older browsers). Some text is also present in the markup, but positioned outside the view-port.

The site you supplied as example uses an image and the feedback functionality is a widget:

```
a#uservoice-feedback-tab {
    background-color: #FF6600;
    background-image: url("http://cdn.uservoice.com/images/widgets/en/feedback_tab_white.png");
}
```

Comment: See the edit. I would recommend using firebug or a similar developer tool too see for yourself what happens *behind the scenes*.

Answer (score 1):

It's an image, because only the newest browsers support CSS 2D transforms. Although in theory, you could use 2D transforms and add support for IE8- by using the proprietary DXImage filters. But then, you couldn't get support for other older browsers without equivalent support (Safari 2, Firefox 2.0, Opera 9, etc.).

Comment: If you're using Chrome or Safari, right-click on the element and choose "Inspect element" and it'll show you the HTML.